# I want to be able to display ads using this implementation for an android app created with Qt cmake

Tags: java, c++, qt

So I'm developing an android app using Qt with Cmake and I want to add ads using admob.I found a github project about an implementation of ads using admob : https://github.com/yevgeniy-logachev/QtAdMob/tree/52a358369a4fc13f6908f1f223a17d1ee8899cab .The project use an older version of qt so I updated the files to respect the new libs(From QAndroidJniObject->QJniObject,etc.).I implemented 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:22.2.0' in the build.gradle and I modified the .xml file how the instruction from git showed me + I added the app unit id from admob.I created a link to the java file as well.So the problem is when I try to run it on emulator I get this application output:

```
D EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xec37ed40: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xec39ea90)
W libuntitled_x86.so: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method "Lorg/qtproject/qt/android/bindings/QtActivity;.InitializeAdBanner()V"
W libuntitled_x86.so:   at org.qtproject.qt.android.QtNative.startQtApplication(Native Method)
W libuntitled_x86.so:   at org.qtproject.qt.android.QtNative$7.run(QtNative.java:442)
W libuntitled_x86.so:   at org.qtproject.qt.android.QtThread$1.run(QtThread.java:25)
W libuntitled_x86.so:   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
07-07 21:59:12.861  8320  8349 W libuntitled_x86.so:
W libuntitled_x86.so: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method "Lorg/qtproject/qt/android/bindings/QtActivity;.SetAdBannerUnitId(Ljava/lang/String;)V"
W libuntitled_x86.so:   at org.qtproject.qt.android.QtNative.startQtApplication(Native Method)
W libuntitled_x86.so:   at org.qtproject.qt.android.QtNative$7.run(QtNative.java:442)
W libuntitled_x86.so:   at org.qtproject.qt.android.QtThread$1.run(QtThread.java:25)
W libuntitled_x86.so:   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
07-07 21:59:12.863  8320  8349 W libuntitled_x86.so:
W libuntitled_x86.so: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method "Lorg/qtproject/qt/android/bindings/QtActivity;.AddAdTestDevice(Ljava/lang/String;)V"
W libuntitled_x86.so:   at org.qtproject.qt.android.QtNative.startQtApplication(Native Method)
W libuntitled_x86.so:   at org.qtproject.qt.android.QtNative$7.run(QtNative.java:442)
W libuntitled_x86.so:   at org.qtproject.qt.android.QtThread$1.run(QtThread.java:25)
W libuntitled_x86.so:   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
07-07 21:59:12.865  8320  8349 W libuntitled_x86.so:
W libuntitled_x86.so: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method "Lorg/qtproject/qt/android/bindings/QtActivity;.ShowAdBanner()V"
W libuntitled_x86.so:   at org.qtproject.qt.android.QtNative.startQtApplication(Native Method)
W libuntitled_x86.so:   at org.qtproject.qt.android.QtNative$7.run(QtNative.java:442)
W libuntitled_x86.so:   at org.qtproject.qt.android.QtThread$1.run(QtThread.java:25)
W libuntitled_x86.so:   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
07-07 21:59:12.866  8320  8349 W libuntitled_x86.so:
W libuntitled_x86.so: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method "Lorg/qtproject/qt/android/bindings/QtActivity;.LoadAdInterstitialWithUnitId(Ljava/lang/String;)V"
W libuntitled_x86.so:   at org.qtproject.qt.android.QtNative.startQtApplication(Native Method)
W libuntitled_x86.so:   at org.qtproject.qt.android.QtNative$7.run(QtNative.java:442)
W libuntitled_x86.so:   at org.qtproject.qt.android.QtThread$1.run(QtThread.java:25)
W libuntitled_x86.so:   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
07-07 21:59:12.867  8320  8349 W libuntitled_x86.so:
W libuntitled_x86.so: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method "Lorg/qtproject/qt/android/bindings/QtActivity;.GetAdBannerWidth()I"
W libuntitled_x86.so:   at org.qtproject.qt.android.QtNative.startQtApplication(Native Method)
W libuntitled_x86.so:   at org.qtproject.qt.android.QtNative$7.run(QtNative.java:442)
W libuntitled_x86.so:   at org.qtproject.qt.android.QtThread$1.run(QtThread.java:25)
W libuntitled_x86.so:   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
07-07 21:59:13.140  8320  8349 W libuntitled_x86.so:
W libuntitled_x86.so: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method "Lorg/qtproject/qt/android/bindings/QtActivity;.GetAdBannerHeight()I"
W libuntitled_x86.so:   at org.qtproject.qt.android.QtNative.startQtApplication(Native Method)
W libuntitled_x86.so:   at org.qtproject.qt.android.QtNative$7.run(QtNative.java:442)
W libuntitled_x86.so:   at org.qtproject.qt.android.QtThread$1.run(QtThread.java:25)
W libuntitled_x86.so:   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
07-07 21:59:13.142  8320  8349 W libuntitled_x86.so:
W libuntitled_x86.so: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method "Lorg/qtproject/qt/android/bindings/QtActivity;.SetAdBannerPosition(II)V"
W libuntitled_x86.so:   at org.qtproject.qt.android.QtNative.startQtApplication(Native Method)
W libuntitled_x86.so:   at org.qtproject.qt.android.QtNative$7.run(QtNative.java:442)
W libuntitled_x86.so:   at org.qtproject.qt.android.QtThread$1.run(QtThread.java:25)
W libuntitled_x86.so:   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
07-07 21:59:13.143  8320  8349 W libuntitled_x86.so:
W libuntitled_x86.so: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method "Lorg/qtproject/qt/android/bindings/QtActivity;.GetAdBannerWidth()I"
W libuntitled_x86.so:   at org.qtproject.qt.android.QtNative.startQtApplication(Native Method)
W libuntitled_x86.so:   at org.qtproject.qt.android.QtNative$7.run(QtNative.java:442)
W libuntitled_x86.so:   at org.qtproject.qt.android.QtThread$1.run(QtThread.java:25)
W libuntitled_x86.so:   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
07-07 21:59:13.152  8320  8349 W libuntitled_x86.so:
W libuntitled_x86.so: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method "Lorg/qtproject/qt/android/bindings/QtActivity;.GetAdBannerHeight()I"
W libuntitled_x86.so:   at org.qtproject.qt.android.QtNative.startQtApplication(Native Method)
W libuntitled_x86.so:   at org.qtproject.qt.android.QtNative$7.run(QtNative.java:442)
W libuntitled_x86.so:   at org.qtproject.qt.android.QtThread$1.run(QtThread.java:25)
W libuntitled_x86.so:   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
07-07 21:59:13.153  8320  8349 W libuntitled_x86.so:
W libuntitled_x86.so: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method "Lorg/qtproject/qt/android/bindings/QtActivity;.SetAdBannerPosition(II)V"
W libuntitled_x86.so:   at org.qtproject.qt.android.QtNative.startQtApplication(Native Method)
W libuntitled_x86.so:   at org.qtproject.qt.android.QtNative$7.run(QtNative.java:442)
W libuntitled_x86.so:   at org.qtproject.qt.android.QtThread$1.run(QtThread.java:25)
W libuntitled_x86.so:   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

I think the implementation for xml file and build.gradle to be ok.Xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="org.qtproject.example" android:installLocation="auto" android:versionCode="-- %%INSERT_VERSION_CODE%% --" android:versionName="-- %%INSERT_VERSION_NAME%% --">
    <!-- %%INSERT_PERMISSIONS -->
    <!-- %%INSERT_FEATURES -->
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:smallScreens="true"/>
    <application android:name="org.qtproject.qt.android.bindings.QtApplication" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:label="-- %%INSERT_APP_NAME%% --" android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" android:allowNativeHeapPointerTagging="false" android:allowBackup="true" android:fullBackupOnly="false">
        <activity android:name="org.dreamdev.QtAdMob.QtAdMobActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|uiMode|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|layoutDirection|locale|fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|mcc|mnc|density" android:label="-- %%INSERT_APP_NAME%% --" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:screenOrientation="unspecified" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name" android:value="-- %%INSERT_APP_LIB_NAME%% --"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.arguments" android:value="-- %%INSERT_APP_ARGUMENTS%% --"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.extract_android_style" android:value="minimal"/>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent">
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name" android:value="QtAdMob"/>
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-9947680780884532~3377759498"/>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
</manifest>
```

As well for build.gradle :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.1'
    }
}

repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar', '*.aar'])
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:22.2.0'
}

android {
    /*******************************************************
     * The following variables:
     * - androidBuildToolsVersion,
     * - androidCompileSdkVersion
     * - qtAndroidDir - holds the path to qt android files
     *                   needed to build any Qt application
     *                   on Android.
     *
     * are defined in gradle.properties file. This file is
     * updated by QtCreator and androiddeployqt tools.
     * Changing them manually might break the compilation!
     *******************************************************/

    compileSdkVersion androidCompileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion androidBuildToolsVersion
    ndkVersion androidNdkVersion

    // Extract native libraries from the APK
    packagingOptions.jniLibs.useLegacyPackaging true

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = [qtAndroidDir + '/src', 'src', 'java']
            aidl.srcDirs = [qtAndroidDir + '/src', 'src', 'aidl']
            res.srcDirs = [qtAndroidDir + '/res', 'res']
            resources.srcDirs = ['resources']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
       }
    }

    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        options.incremental = true
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    // Do not compress Qt binary resources file
    aaptOptions {
        noCompress 'rcc'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        resConfig "en"
        minSdkVersion qtMinSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion qtTargetSdkVersion
        ndk.abiFilters = qtTargetAbiList.split(",")
    }
}
```

This is the implementation for Cmake:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(untitled VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/android CACHE INTERNAL "")

find_package(QT NAMES Qt6 Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets)
find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets)

set(ANDROID_SOURCES_DIR ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/android/src)
file(GLOB_RECURSE ANDROID_JAVA_SOURCES "${ANDROID_SOURCES_DIR}/*.java")

add_library(AndroidSources OBJECT ${ANDROID_JAVA_SOURCES})
target_include_directories(AndroidSources PRIVATE ${ANDROID_SOURCES_DIR})

set(PROJECT_SOURCES
    main.cpp
    mainwindow.cpp
    mainwindow.h
    mainwindow.ui
    QtAdMobBannerAndroid.cpp
    QtAdMobBannerDummy.cpp
    QtAdMobInterstitialAndroid.cpp
    QtAdMobInterstitialDummy.cpp
    QtAdmobBanner.cpp
    QtAdmobInterstitial.cpp
    QtAdMobBannerIos.mm
    QtAdMobInterstitialIos.mm
    IQtAdMobBanner.h
    QtAdMobBannerAndroid.h
    QtAdMobBannerIos.h
    QtAdMobBannerDummy.h
    QtAdMobBanner.h
    IQtAdMobInterstitial.h
    QtAdMobInterstitial.h
    QtAdMobInterstitialIos.h
    QtAdMobInterstitialAndroid.h
    QtAdMobInterstitialDummy.h
)

if(${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} GREATER_EQUAL 6)
    qt_add_executable(untitled
        MANUAL_FINALIZATION
        ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
    )
else()
    if(ANDROID)
        add_library(untitled SHARED
            ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
        )
        set(ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/android")
    else()
        add_executable(untitled
            ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
        )
    endif()
endif()

target_link_libraries(untitled PRIVATE
    Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Widgets
    AndroidSources
)

set_target_properties(untitled PROPERTIES
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_GUI_IDENTIFIER my.example.com
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_BUNDLE_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_SHORT_VERSION_STRING ${PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE TRUE
    WIN32_EXECUTABLE TRUE
)

install(TARGETS untitled
    BUNDLE DESTINATION .
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}
)

if(QT_VERSION_MAJOR EQUAL 6)
    qt_finalize_executable(untitled)
endif()
```

And the java code is the same as the code in the project from Git.

I found out the problem and is because the code from java is not used but I don't know why.

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/QtDigitalAdvertising/examples.html

Comment: @Bop I can't install qt digital advetising in the installer for any version of qt.